# SQL recursive Parent-Child relationship with MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, parent-child, recursive-query

i have a mysql 5.5 database with the following schema:

```
ADDRESS
id   city   street
___________________ 
1     a      b
2     a      c
3     v      d

GROUP_LIST
group_id group_parent_id
___________________ 
1           NULL
2           1
3           1

ADDRESS_IN_GROUPS
address_id   group_id
___________________ 
1              1
2              1
3              2
```

I need a query that from a group id, join the data to retrieve all addresses linked to a group_id and his children and sub-children.

I saw many posts that use **CTE** for doing these recursion query, but my mysql version not support that.

Thank you

Comment: Does you have only 2 nesting levels in your data, or the depth is dynamic?

Comment: @akina i have more than 20 levels.

Comment: If so there is no reasonable solution in single query form (joining 20 table copies looks like idiocy). Solve the task in stored procedure format. Or upgrade your server to version 8+ and use recursive CTE.

Comment: I can't do neither options. I only can make queries.

Comment: If you have no permissions for to create stored procedure then the only option is to perform this task on the client side.

Comment: Ok. So how i can do it?

Comment: I don't know what is your client and what instruments you have in your programming language/framework.

Comment: No frameworks. The interations between mysql and client was made by PHP MySQLi extension.

Comment: Well, do it on PHP. MySQL only provides the data for processing.